# Bind mount in an encrypted systemd-homed

Tags: systemd, fstab, bind-mount

I use to have a directory, lets call it `F`, in my home directory, so I normally did `cd /home/me/F`. (or variants)

My home directory is encrypted with luks using systemd-homed. Since `F` grew too much, I move it to a secondary drive which is mounted in `/mnt/F`. However, I would like to bind mount it in my home so I can still do `cd /home/me/F`. A symlink is not enough, since cmake complains it can't follow symlinks, so it must be a bind mount.

Since my home directory doesn't really exist until is mounted by systemd-homed, how could I do the bind mount of `F`?

Comment: suggestion: you could take a look at pam_mount. As  systemd-homed too appears to rely on PAM, you'd have to be careful with interactions and ordering between both. Breaking PAM might prevent any kind of login to the system.